# Analytically continued function with integer coefficients

Tags: complex-analysis

The function $z\mapsto \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}e^nz^n$ is analytic around $0$ and can be analytically continued on $[-1,0]$ since $ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}e^nz^n=\frac1{1-ez}$ for all $z\in D(0,e^{-1})$.

I am looking for a sequence $(b_n)_{n\ge0}$ of integers such that $\sum_{n\ge0}b_nz^n$ is analytic around $0$ and can be analytically continued on $[-1,0]$ and $b_n\sim_{+\infty} e^n$.

Any hints or solution will be welcome. Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by $b_n\simeq e^n$?

Comment: I meant $b_n\sim_{+\infty} e^n$, that is $\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{b_n}{e^n}=1$. I edit my post.

Comment: Ok. How about $b_n=\lfloor e^n\rfloor$ then?

Comment: I thought about this sequence, but I did not manage to prove that the function $\sum_{n\ge0}b_nz^n$ can be analitycally continued on $[-1,0]$. Do you have an idea to do this?

Comment: the radius of convergence of $\sum_{n \ge 0} (e^n - \lfloor e^n \rfloor) z^n$  is $1$, with a pole at $z = 1$,  but does it have a pole at $z= -1$ ?

Comment: Maybe try to use the inequalities $\lfloor e^n\rfloor\leq e^n\leq \lfloor e^n\rfloor+1$